# Importing huge .stl Files / unsigned long long

Tags: python

I have code, which imports a .stl file and does stuff with it.

Currently I am testing the limitations of this code and ran into a problem.
When importing .stl files with a huge amount of vertices I am running into an Error:

```
    array length mismatch (expected -375467073, got 429839295)
```

The .stl has around 40bn vertices, so I was expecting problems coming my way, but not exactly this. I also got other error messages but blender crashed shortly after and I was unable to copy other errors.

I already found out that I am capping out an unsigned long, which produces the error.
Is there a way to tell blender to import the .stl while using unsigned long long?
Why even is python struggling with datatypes anyways?

Comment: Python isn't so much struggling as it is simple.  It was an early design decision that ints should be " implemented as “long” integer objects of arbitrary size."  You can't tell Python to use UlL ints.  You could try writing an STL importer that uses bignum but at 40B vertices you're going to run into a lot of other issues with algorithms that aren't designed to scale to that size.

Comment: @MartyFouts I see, thank you :D

Comment: Regardless of the file format, you'll have trouble working with 40 Bn vertices, let alone display them in the viewport